# I can't install “lockfile-progs” which is necessary for “log check” by HOMEBREW on YOSEMITE

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have upgraded my Mac OS X to 10.10, Yosemite, but things go wrong. For other commands, I've succeeded to re-build those programs.

However `logcheck`, which is installed by [homebrew](http://brew.sh) can't work well since the `lockfile-progs` is a prerequisite. The error message is:

```
fatal: lockfile-progs is a prerequisite for logcheck, and was not found.
```

But I can't find the way to install the `lockfile-progs` to Yosemite. Is there any advice for this situation?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this, i am seeing the same error on catalina

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug; you should report it to Homebrew.